# django modelformset exclude ID field

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-forms

I have a modelformset that I've created in a view as such:

```
    CarpoolFamilyInviteModelFormset = modelformset_factory(CarpoolFamilyInvite, fields=('family_name','family_email'), extra=3)
```

As you can see, I've tried to limit it to two fields:  family_name and family_email.  However, when I render it in the template, I get an extra field, ID.  Here's the template code:

```
            {% for form in formset %}
                <div class="row">
                {% for field in form %}
                    <div class="span3">
                        <input id="focusedInput" class="input-large focused" type="text" placeholder="{{ field.label }}">
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

and here's what the form looks like:

[image]

Any idea how I can skip showing the ID fields? exclude="ID" doesn't seem to have any effect. THanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The model formset relies on the id field, so it is not possible to exclude it.

The best option is to render the id field as a hidden field. See the docs for [looping over hidden and visible fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#looping-over-hidden-and-visible-fields) for an example.